# React-bootstrap: Carousel carousel indicator

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I use React Bootstrap carousel. The indicator buttons are not aligned properly and the size is also off. Is there a way to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwYCa.jpg

```xml
<Grid>
    <Row >
        <Col md={6} md={12}>
            <Carousel>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7c0dpVFdGbGl0MWs"/>

                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7MVAySV9jME9TWWM"/>

                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item >
                    <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7N250S3JicmxxNmM"/>

                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item >
                    <img   src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7MDF5Vm1VYWhoY3M"/>

                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item >
                    <img  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7X1ROMUxRMjVsN00"/>

                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: I havn't used any css on the carousel. I used the default example from the react-boostrap website. I don't know why it is rendering the buttons like that. Even when I'm copying the exact demo code from react boostrap, it renders exactly how I have it in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image heights to the height of the carousel:

```
<Carousel>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/assets/carousel.png"/>
    </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```